# Rails: How do I have a zero if there is no data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently if a user sells something they would see a box witha price. If they haven't sold something the box disapears and all they see is Sales. How do I leave a number like $0 if the user didn't sell something instead of a clear blank?

Thanks

```
<% if current_user %>
              <sold> 
              <li><%= link_to "Sales", current_user %>
              <% @sales.each do |sale| %>
            <div class="sold-count">$<%= sale.amount / 100 %></ %></div>  </li> </sold>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're iterating over the `sales` for each sale, but if the size of the container is zero, then the loop is going to be skipped.

You need to add a conditional to check to see if `sales` is empty, `@sales.empty?` and if it is, then show `0`.

```
<% if @sales.empty? %>
    <div class="sold-count"> $0 </div>  </li> </sold>
<% end %>
```